# Finding text in LIKE in a big table

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have two tables, the first one contains a list of emails with their subjects (~600k rows) [their index is id_mail], the second is a list of ids (~135k rows) [the id is called numero_protocollo].

I need to pair the two knowing that they are connected if the numero_protocollo is part of the subject, so my idea is to try to join them with a like.

My initial code was:

```
select bm.id_mail, cm.numero_protocollo
from bigbox_mail bm
inner join costituzione_mora cm on bm.subject like '%'||cm.numero_protocollo||'%'
```

but it freezes (clearly, the amount of combinations to try is crazy).

So I tried to build a code in PHP that takes a numero_protocollo and looks through every email and bonds them, still too much computationally speaking.
I even tried to chuck it into sets of 100 emails but is still too much.

Any tip on how to do it?

Comment: Indexing or Elasticsearch

Comment: What you're looking for is "full text indexing" and while Oracle might have some functionality for this, a separate purpose-built solution like Elasticsearch may still out-perform.

Comment: Is numero_protocollo just a number like 123 that you'd find in subjects like 'Answer to issue 123' and 'Order of 123 items'?

Comment: When saving the email subject lines, split them into words and look them up against the other table to see what word is a numero_protocollo value, and record that value in its own field, which you can index. Then the lookup later is very easy. You want to get away from multiple pieces of information per field as quickly as possible. Or, if the subject line is strictly patterned in a reliable fashion, you can also create a function that parses it out and then a virtual column over that function which you can also index. In either case, you should get to where you can use an equality join.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's alphanumeric and with a "-", so like LM-12345-CC or CM-123456-1234-TT

Comment: @PaulW I could do something like this, the problem is that the data is already stored but I can do everything chunk by chunk, exploding by space every subject and looking for each word in the id table, If I find a result it's like making a join. I will only lose the emails where the numero_protocollo in the subject is not divided from a space (few cases). The most amount of words that I have in a subject is 74 so it should be fine.

Comment: You don't want to do that at query time. Consider a virtual column that calls a deterministic function with the subject line, and that function runs through the words and does the lookup and finds and returns the right word. Then create an index on the virtual column, which materializes the result in the index, allowing for equality joins. Just be sure any dependencies (your lookup table) is populated first, as the declared determinism of the function will cause it to get stale if the data it depends on changes (e.g. if it isn't really deterministic).

Comment: @PaulW ok got it, what happens if in the subject there are multiple numero_procollo? this method would find only the first referenced, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you have this issue then you'll need a child table to hold the numero_protocollo values scraped from the subject line. And that throws out the virtual column idea. You'd need to write a scheduled job that scanned the table and populated the child table with its findings. That's getting ugly. You *could* denormalize and have two or three virtual cols representing 1st 2nd and 3rd from the subject line, but that will complicate your queries (requiring OR expansion). Either possibility could work, but neither is elegant. This is the cost of non-organized data in an RDBMS.

Comment: Another option is to live with the inefficiency of the LIKE '%...%' but figure out a way to include another join key, like maybe date or date range or anything that could reduce the possible rows to look at. Index that, followed by the subject line on the right side of the index column list. Or, if all else fails, crank up parallel query with a parallel hint and brute force your way through it.

Comment: @PaulW I can try these options, tbh I think that the cases with multiple numero_protocollo are isolated. What do you mean by "This is the cost of non-organized data in an RDBMS"? Sadly they asked me to connect all the emails of the last 10 years to their numero_protocollo (if they have any). So my idea was to save the basic info (sender, receiver, subject) and look for the numero_protocollo  (in reality I should look also in the body but I thought it was too much data). I don't think I have many other options to do this task. Would have you done it differently?

Comment: An email is unorganized. You're dealing with free-text which has no fixed order or standard, making it very difficult to write efficient and clean SQL to process meaningful bits of information buried within. This isn't something we normally store in a database. You can do it, it's just going to take some extra doing. I would consider writing a scheduled job that scans through the content and pulls out the key data points and writes them to another key-pair table, which can then be indexed and joined at query time to find any email with any one of those key data pieces.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a static set of data, you could add a new column to store the numero_protocollo to the email table, and then write a PHP script to loop through each email and pull the numero_protocollo out of the email subject (using a regex) and store it to the new column.

Comment: If the subjects guarantee that the number can be determined by some rule (e.g. because it's always the only number in the string or because it is always enclosed by brackets or the like), then the idea of an extra column is great. You don't need PHP for this. Just create the column as a virtual (i.e. computed)  column and create an index on that column.

Comment: It's a wonderful idea, the only problem is that the numero_protocollo hasn't a specific format. Sometimes is like AB-123456-CC but it can be like CM-12345678--304950-KK.
One other problem is that in a subject there could be a list of numero_protocollo, so che connection is not 1:1